# phpunit not working when I pass parameter

Tags: php, phpunit

when I run my test with this command -> phpunit, all my test are running, but if I pass parameter like  phpunit --group models or  phpunit --list-group  or phpunit --verbose ... Can someone can help me please? Thank

[image]

[image: Arbo]

Here my phpunit.xml  content

```
<phpunit bootstrap="bootstrap.php"
colors="true"
convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
processIsolation="false"
stopOnFailure="false"
syntaxCheck="false"
verbose="true">

<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
        <directory>../tests/</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

And here my TestCase.php content

```
<?php

class TestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

      protected $CI;

      public function setUp()
      {
          $this->CI = &get_instance();
      }

      public function tearDown()
      {
          $this->CI = &get_instance();
      }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The command you're providing is wrong, you forgot to mention `group`

```
phpunit --group test_bad_spelling
```

And then it's `--list-groups` not `--list-group` (singular) 
Have a look at [PHPUnit Chapter 3. The Command-Line Test Runner](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html)